# rethinkdb java api outofmemoryerror exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, rethinkdb

i have a big document file ( ~1.5 gb ~430.000 line). The program read document file line by line and insert each row into rethinkdb. But I get this error between 11000-12000 lines. What would be the reason?

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread    at
>   java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:678)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   com.rethinkdb.net.Connection.connect(Connection.java:105)
>   ~[rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.rethinkdb.net.Connection.reconnect(Connection.java:94)
>   ~[rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.rethinkdb.net.Connection.reconnect(Connection.java:83)
>   ~[rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.rethinkdb.net.Connection$Builder.connect(Connection.java:422)
>   ~[rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.config.RethinkDBConnectionFactory.createConnection(RethinkDBConnectionFactory.java:17)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.service.InserterService.insertData(InserterService.java:33)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.service.InserterService.insertData(InserterService.java:38)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.InserterApplication.batchInsert(InserterApplication.java:168)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.InserterApplication.fileModeIndex(InserterApplication.java:97)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.InserterApplication.run(InserterApplication.java:57)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:788)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:778)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.InserterApplication.main(InserterApplication.java:37)
>   [classes/:na]

**RethinkDBConnectionFactory.java**

```
public class RethinkDBConnectionFactory {

    private final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;

    private String host;

    public RethinkDBConnectionFactory(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public Connection createConnection() {
        return r.connection().hostname(host).connect();
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

}
```

**InserterService**

```
@Service
public class InserterService {

    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InserterService.class);

    private final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;

    @Autowired
    private RethinkDBConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void insertData(Activity activity) {
        oMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        Map<Object, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(activity, Map.class);
        r.db("test").table("twitter").insert(map).run(connectionFactory.createConnection());
    }

}
```

**RethinkDBConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.erdem.rethinkdb.inserter.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class RethinkDBConfiguration {

    @Value("${rethinkdb.host}")
    private String DBHOST;

    @Bean
    public RethinkDBConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new RethinkDBConnectionFactory(DBHOST);
    }

    @Bean
    public DbInitializer dbInitializer() {
        return new DbInitializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code...

Comment: i will update...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, where or how the file is read; I'd presume, that the error is there.  You can always try using Eclipse MAT, and a -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to get the heapdump, and just check, what's wrong.

Comment: i have a multiple big files. 3gb 2gb 500.000+ line.I was tried other doc files. I got same error. Note: In the same logic and same code block, there is no problem when indexing to ElasticSearch. i think problem is rethinkdb connector.

Comment: Maybe you need to close the connection again, after you're creating it.  Is your solution using a connection pool, too? Just as a performance optimization...

Comment: I open and close the connection for each insert. Nothing changed.

Comment: And did you check the heapdump, yet?

Comment: I thought it was a mistake in my code. I think I've written it in a structure that will consume memory all the time. I got rid of the error using a more stable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting those objects line per line, at this point you're mapping 430k lines and keeping them in memory which might cause issues when you're inserting them into the DB

Or increase JVM memory allocation